# Calling a function from linked shared object .so in microcontroller causes it to jump to invalid memory space

Tags: object, linker, libraries, shared

I made a simple .so file with a single function returning the number 42. 
I build my object like this:
`arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic fooLib.c  -mcpu=cortex-m4`
And my shared object like this:
`arm-none-eabi-gcc -shared -o libfoo.so fooLib.o`
I linked and get no compilation errors and no "Undefined function" errors
when calling the function. I also included the header etc..
Code executes but when I trigger the event that causes the function call
I get into a hardfault because of the code trying to jump to invalid space

```
#0  0x10001896 in HardFault_Handler ()
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#3  0x100008b6 in datsBtnCback (btn=<optimized out>) at dats_main.c:842
```

Using a shred in object in a microcontroller is foreign to me to begin with but I believe it should be possible? And  i do know using a statically linked lib is the way but the question is concerning THIS method if it is even possible?

I am not sure how to analyze my elf or other files to perhaps find an offset of where the function really lives.